# ros::Time::isValid doesn't do what we think it does?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, roscpp, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the documentation (http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1Time.html#a84cd12a499c70fb3eefce89cda2b6113), ros::Time::isValid returns "whether or not the current time is valid.  Time is valid if it is non-zero".

However, a trivial example is enough to show that the implementation does not do this:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "rostime_example");
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    // default construct a time
    ros::Time t;

    ROS_WARN_STREAM("time value: " <<t.toSec());
    ROS_WARN_STREAM("time valid: " <<t.isValid());

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
ivaughn@ros-pc:~/test_ws$ rosrun rostime_example node 
[ WARN] [1561399516.961348750]: time value: 0
[ WARN] [1561399516.961420491]: time valid: 1
```

Any idea what's going on here?  Is this just a bug in ROS 1, or am I misunderstanding how this function is expected to behave.

We're kind of curious, behavior that does something different when a timestamp is invalid is often safety-critical.  Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326824/ros::time::isvalid-doesn%27t-do-what-we-think-it-does?/) by [ivaughn_whoi](https://answers.ros.org/users/33224/ivaughn_whoi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-06-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this is due to a misunderstanding of the comment on `isValid()`.

The documentation indeed states ([here](https://github.com/ros/roscpp_core/blob/325f72f53015bd04ea0bd0adf62e39b981b4f50c/rostime/include/ros/time.h#L201-L204)):

> Returns whether or not the current time is valid.  Time is valid if it is non-zero.

But "the [..] time" it refers to is not the `Time` *instance*, but "the time", as in: the global ROS time.

A ROS node can use different methods to retrieve the "current time": it can use walltime, a simulation time or something else. The "valid" here essentially returns `true` whenever one of those sources have been selected *and* has been initialised properly.

`0` is chosen as a sentinel value to detect when that is not the case (as it's assumed that `0` is just not a valid value for any source of time (whether that is correct is something else)).

It's slightly confusing that a `ros::Time` instance can also have a `0` value and that `ros::Time::isValid()` is a static method of the `ros::Time` class.

In the code that you show:

> ```
> int main(int argc, char** argv) {
> ```

```
    ros::init(argc, argv, "rostime_example");
    [..]
}
```

`isValid()` will return `true` as soon as you call `ros::init(..)` (as one of its duties is to initialise the time subsystem).

---

We can also take a look at the sources (from [here](https://github.com/ros/roscpp_core/blob/325f72f53015bd04ea0bd0adf62e39b981b4f50c/rostime/src/time.cpp#L324-L327)):

```
bool Time::isValid()
{
  return (!g_use_sim_time) || !g_sim_time.isZero();
}
```

This essentially tells us that "time" is considered "valid" if either we're not using simulation time, or, *if* simulation time is being used, it's `!= 0`.

The `g_` prefixes tell us that this static method is checking globals, not `ros::Time` member variables.

---

Edit: perhaps a nice contribution would be to improve the documentation of this method and to remove the ambiguity.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-24**:
And this is not directed at you, but:

> Is this just a bug in ROS 1, [..]

I like how posters here often insert these sort of statements almost casually in their questions.

**Comment by [ivaughn_whoi](https://answers.ros.org/users/33224/ivaughn_whoi/) on 2019-06-24**:
Yeah, I'd like to make sure I correctly understand what's going on before claiming its a bug.  WIth ROS its more likely to be a documentation issue than anything else.

Pull request: https://github.com/ros/roscpp_core/pull/109